# Touching or moving LED circuit board causes PWM to flicker momentarily. Without touching the board there is no flicker

Tags: mosfet, led, pwm

The circuit shown is set up as a constant current drive.  It turns on and off just fine. When it's fully on the MOSFET on the low side of the LEDs is fully on and doesn't get hot at all and is not partially on.

The issue I am seeing is when I start to PWM the FET from the micro at 70Hz 10% duty cycle. It looks fine with no flicker at all. The issue arises when I touch the PCB. The LEDs will momentarily turn off and on. I've noticed that I can ground myself and touch the PCB and the LEDs no longer flicker, but if I touch the PCB on the edges without being grounded they flicker momentarily.

Further more I notice it only happens on some of the boards. Others do not have this flicker.

Another thing I notice is that applying a scope to the drain to see what's happening the flicker goes away while touching the board.

Any help to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated. I can provide more info as need.

The micro is a SAMC21N18A by microchip. It's running at 3.3 Volts and the I/O pins output are all output 3.3V. The voltage divider is putting on the Mosfet gate is about 3V when fully on. So the PWM is 3V. I see a clean PWM signal with no glitching or additional off time at the gate when I touch the LED board. Also, some LED board don't have this behavior only about 5% do have this behavior out of 50 PCBs.

Every color exhibits this behavior. There are 4 colors of LEDs on the board. None are ever on at the same time.

Also, there majority of the boards that don't have this flicker behavior at all while PWMing. It's only about 5% of the boards that are behaving like this.

Adding a LED directly to the output of the Micro does not exhibit this behavior. It stays on with a 10% duty cycle and no flicker.

The micro is on a separate PCBA with a cable harness connecting the LED board and board with the micro on it. I've A/B tested the LED boards with various micro cable harnesses and the issue follows the LED board.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A loose connection?

Comment: Put a red LED and series resistor across the MCU output. Does it show similar disturbance? What I/O voltage does the MCU put out? Please show us the actual LM317 circuit.

Comment: OK, so what does the PCB look like? Is the PWM 3.3V or 5V? How is the MCU powered and clocked? Reset pin OK? Post the relevant schematics, the LEDs are likely fine but controlled wrong by MCU.

Comment: Also current source may be unstable in some cases. You can add some resistor from _Vled_ to ground and(or) small capacitor from IC output to ground and see what happens. Oscillograms could reveal the cause.

Comment: @Vladimir I will try this. When measuring the drain of the mosfet with an oscilliscope the issue goes away. I was thinking this may be because the scopes input impedance to ground is just enough to stabilize the current driver? If I were to add this small resistance from VLED to ground or small capacitor from IC(LM317) output to ground are there any considerations in picking the values for them?

Comment: Values are hard to say, such circuit is uncommon, and usage of LM317 as current source is not best choice, especially in mass production device, at my opinion. Capacitor could start from hundreds pF up to 0,01 μF, depends of inrush current acceptable, and resistor, i guess, about 10k. LM317 datasheet says that minimal load current is 3,5...10 mA, may be this is what is necessary.

Comment: Thanks it looks like specific load for the LM317 I'm using says 10mA in the data sheet. I used a resistor to ground to set the output to 10mA when the LEDs are disconnected from ground using the FET. Looks like that it resolved the issue. I was optimizing for part count and cost for the constant current driver. Do you have any suggestions for similar constant current drivers to use instead?

Comment: I think, most efficient will be step-down LED driver IC. It has higher efficiency and lower reference voltage (ever more efficient), and many of them has shutdown feature. Then, you will be able to control brightness by this IC and use FETs only for LED selection, this will remove flicker at all and reduce complexity.